# How to add/remove iOS 8 custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I have made a `UITableView` and put images and switches on table view cells, I want to add and remove keyboard programmatically by using switch instead of going in

Setting -> General -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard

Comment: It's not possible using public API. It may be possible using private API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I disable custom keyboards (iOS8) for my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557373/can-i-disable-custom-keyboards-ios8-for-my-app)