# How do you disable a 3rd party keyboard in your iOS app

Tags: uitextfield, uikeyboard

Can you disable 3rd party keyboards in iOS?

If so, how?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557373/can-i-disable-custom-keyboards-ios8-for-my-app

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this method to your UIApplicationDelegate

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier
    {

        if (extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier)
        {
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: How to prove it's working?

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5.1

Add to AppDelegate.Swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
    if (extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier.keyboard.rawValue) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Actually the answer is not correct. The function should be:  `func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool`

Comment: I disagree with the comment above me. For Swift 5, the original answer worked, the comment did not.

Answer (score 0):

Proper swift 5.1 version

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier
) -> Bool {
    return extensionPointIdentifier != UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier.keyboard
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 5.4+ ,it will more swift.

in your class AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
    if(extensionPointIdentifier ==  .keyboard){
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```