# Disable third party keyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

#### Assumptions

I'm using SFSafari with Swift, but I'm having issues with typing on a third-party keyboard, so I'd like to use a standard (hardened) keyboard.

Addendum 1: After clearing the cache of Safari, it is fixed only at the next startup, but it can not be done to clear the cache.  ..  ..

Addendum 2: Opening another application with the keyboard that does not move open, and returning again, it was possible to input.  What's going on inside ... Can this event happen intentionally?

#### The problem you are having

What I want to do is the same as [【Swift】 カスタムキーボードを無効化する](https://qiita.com/tetsukick/items/dce05baf3ecf20be13d9),
 It seems that App Delegate cannot be used on iOS 13 or later, so I wrote it like Scene Delegate, but no error occurs, but even if you execute it, a frozen keyboard of a third party appears.

#### Applicable source code

Code on the site

```
func application (_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier)-> Bool (
     if extensionPointIdentifier == .keyboard {
         return false
     }
     return true
}
```

Code rewritten in Scenne Delegate

```
func scene (_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options a: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier)-> Bool (
         if a == .keyboard {
             return false
         }
         return true
     }
```

#### What I tried

AppDelegate is executed by looking at [here](https://re-engines.com/2019/10/03/%E3%80%90swift%E3%80%91ios13-1%E3%80%81xcode11%E3%81%A7scenedelegate%E5%91%A8%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E8%A7%A6%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82/).
(Deleted the Scene Delegate) => It stopped working normally due to blackout.

There were several different ways to write the contents of scene () without error, so I tried it.

#### Additional information (FW / tool version, etc.)

XCode11.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Basically I was able to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108659/how-do-you-disable-a-3rd-party-keyboard-in-your-ios-app). But I didn't know how to mess with the keyboard with SFSafariViewController, so I used WKWebView. (I used SFSafari because I had a bug and couldn't use it before.)
you should change the line breaks a little.