# Accessing host app's name or identifier when the user starts using the custom keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, custom-keyboard

I am would like to see which app the user is using the custom keyboard when the user starts using it. I am not sure if that information is currently accessible and but so far I was not able to find an answer. I appreciate any help.

I am familiar with the ExtensionPointIdentifier but that's not what I am looking for.
[Can I disable custom keyboards (iOS8) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557373/can-i-disable-custom-keyboards-ios8-for-my-app)